# Maintain multiple state of a single component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the four components.

1. Parent Component(It contains remaining 3 components)
2. ComponentClassA, ComponentClassB(2nd & 3rd components) these components have showresultBtn button which will populates results into **ShowResults** component.
3. ShowResults component(4th component): It will shows name and marks(below the tab of ComponentClassA & ComponentClassB).

ComponentClassA and ComponentClassB are present in tabs. So when user comes to ComponentClassA tab and click on showresultBtn then result will populate in ShowResults component and same with ComponentClassB. so, whenever user navigates and come back to ComponentClassA then result should be maintained and when comes to ComponentClassB then claasB result should mainted.

So far, I am only able to maintained the state of last clicked showresultBtn because last clicked override redux state, but i need to mainted the state of both showresultBtn(ComponentClassA and ComponentClassB)

---

| Parent Component..............................................|

|.............................................................................|

| ComponentClassA Tab| ComponentClassB Tab            |

|...........................................................................|

|...........................................................................|

|...........................................................................|

|ShowResults Component..................................|

|...........................................................................|

|...........................................................................|

|_____________________________________|

Comment: Try to make what your're saying more clear.  This is difficult to grapple with. 

But what I think you need todo is add an additional key:value in your state to populate from, if I'm correctly understanding you.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] so it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using the same state in Redux.

Try this,

You need to maintain two states in Redux for the two components. 
And pass that state to the Results Component.

If Component A pass A state from Redux to Result Component.
If component B pass B state from Redux to Result Component.

Else, please share the code or a better understanding of what are you doing.